# Using the Fourier Series of $f(t)=(t-\frac{1}{2})^{2}$ to deduce the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, summation, fourier-series

So this is a question in one of the previous tests:

[image]

- **My approach** (**if you want just skip to step 3.**):$$$$
  **1. Formulation of the problem and calculating the constant term of the series $a_o$**

I reproduced the curve using even symmetry, and proceeded to find the constant term first.

[image]

$$$$

**2. Finding the n-th coefficient term $a_n$**

[image]
$$$$
**3. Writing the Fourier series and then substituting a vale at the boundary of the periodic curve to get the formula, the final result is not correct, of course.**

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with LaTeX? You'll need to rewrite everything in it if you expect an answer on here (that's just the way it works, it's a lot clearer to all). Shouldn't take too long

Answer (score 1):

You have now

$$\left(  \left| t \right| -1/2 \right) ^{2}=1/12+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }2\,{\frac {\cos \left( n\pi \,t \right)  \left(  \left( -1 \right) ^{n
}+1 \right) }{{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}}}
$$

Then it is reduced to

$$\left(  \left| t \right| -1/2 \right) ^{2}=1/12+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {\cos \left( 2\,n\pi \,t \right) }{{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}}}
$$

Evaluating the last equation at $t=0$ we obtain

$$1/4=1/12+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}}}$$

and finally we have

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{n}^{-2}= {\frac {{\pi }^{2}}{6}}$$